# Make my navbar show when reaching a certain section #?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I make my navbar in react make show only when reaching a certain section ? In this case it is the #about section. Because currently I am doing it by checking the scroll position the problem with that is on larger screens the scrollpositions differs so I need to make sure that the navbar becomes fixed only when #about is reached. Currently I am doing it like that:

```
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setSrollPosition(position);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
<TheAppBar position={scrollPosition > 670 ? "fixed" : "static"} id="about">
```

Comment: Interceptor Observer could be a solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API. This way, when about section is visible you can dispatch a callback function..

Comment: Maybe you could try to use some of the packages checking if component is in viewport, for example react-in-viewport or react-in-view

Answer (score 0):

## By leveraging [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

In this example we attach a `ref` to the `#about` section. `Element.getBoundingClientRect().top` will basically return the distance between that element and the top of the viewport in unit pixels. In this example I subtract the `window.innerHeight` from it, so that the we can instead base the condition off of the bottom of the viewport instead of the top. Note that you might also want to consider the `resize` event as well not just the `scroll` event for full responsiveness.

```js
function App() {

  const aboutSectionRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleWindowScrollAndResize = e => {
    console.clear();
    if ((aboutSectionRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight) <= 0) {
      console.log("===== about section reached =====");
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleWindowScrollAndResize);
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowScrollAndResize);
    
    return (()=>{
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleWindowScrollAndResize);
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowScrollAndResize);
    })
    
  }, [handleWindowScrollAndResize])

  return(
    <div>
      <p style={{height: "1000px", minHeight: "120vh"}}>scroll down</p>
      <div id="about" ref={aboutSectionRef} style={{height: "2000px", background: "grey"}}><h2>about section</h2> <p>I am the about section. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
      <footer style={{height: "500px"}}>i am a footer</footer>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```